# Should it be "you and I" or "you and me" in the song "We are the world"

Tags: poetry, personal-pronouns, grammatical-case, songs

In the song "We are the world" by Michael Jackson and Lionel Ritchie, there are these [lyrics](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/michaeljackson/weretheworldusaforafrica.html):

> "We are the world,
>
> We are the children
>
> We are the ones who make a brighter day
>
> So, let's start giving
>
> There's a choice we're making
>
> We're saving our own lives
>
> It's true we'll make a better day
>
> Just you and me"

Should the last line be "you and I"? Because the meaning is "you and I will make a better day".

Actually Michael Jackson asked this same question in the [recording session](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3hW3HukKhg&t=0s), and someone (likely Quincy Jones) told him to sing "you and me". Is there any principal reason for this choice of words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically speaking, *you and I* is correct, but clearly the wording was changed to make the song sound better. Try imagining the song with the word *I* instead of *me* and you'll get what I mean.

Comment: To me, it sounds better but misleading. Once I thought it meant "make a better day for you and me". Is this really misleading for native listener? Is it worth the trade-off?

Comment: @thn , you could always call it poetic license!!

Comment: And, @thn , native listeners are unlikely to be confused. That rule is often bent in modern speech.

Comment: Actually I prefer "you and I". The other one is poetic but not politically correct, because the theme of the song is to encourage people to actively do the good things. "You and me" makes it sound passive, which harms the theme.

Comment: @thn , fair enough, that's a nice point! Well, I'll listen to the song and get back to you. Why do you use the word 'politically correct' , though?

Comment: Oh I made mistake, it seems "politically correct" has some specific meanings like the censorship of words to avoid offensive. In this case should I say "do not do justice to the song" instead?

Comment: @thn , that's what I thought! Yeah, you've rephrased it in a better manner.

Comment: "Hoping we'll all pull through, me and you" (Pete Seeger) is another similar example. It's grammatically wrong, but it rhymes! Fortunately, he didn't say "God's counting on you, God's counting on I."

Answer (score 2):

imagine there being no "you and". it will be awkward to say "just I", but not to say "just me", so it should be "just me

Comment: Interesting point

Answer (score 0):

You and I is not only grammatically correct but also works better as a rhyme with the preceding line: “we’re saving our own lives.”